# Series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^u}{k!}$---something known?

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

Define $f(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^u}{k!}$ for natural numbers $u$. Using maple I can find the sum for specific values of $u$, but there is no general answer (unsurprisingly). All values I found are integer multiples of $e$. Below is a short table (omitting $e$), which cannot be found in the OEIS

```
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   5
4   15
5   52
6   203
7   877
8   4140
9   21147
10  115975
```

What is known about this sequence, or the associated function we get by extending the argument $u$ to the nonnegative real line?

There should be no problems in differentiating term by term, and so we find the derivatives
$$
   f^{(n)}(u)=\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{k^u (\log k)^n}{k!}
$$
so all the derivatives are positive.

Comment: These are [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), known on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000110) as well.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3112898/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bk%5Eu%7D%7Bk!%7D%24)

Comment: Thanks, that answers the Q, Also thanks for the search engine, will be bookmarked! @Martin R